# Do we differentiate [tag:autism] and [tag:asperger]?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

We currently have separate tags for [autism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism) and [asperger](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asperger).  In 2013 the DSM-5 changed [Asperger Syndrome](https://www.autismspeaks.org/what-autism/asperger-syndrome) to fall under the general umbrella of the Autism spectrum.  However, there is a distinct culture and community of individuals with Aspergers, and treating it as merely a subset of Autism seems inaccurate.

There are currently 7 questions tagged [autism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism).  2 of those are also tagged [asperger](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asperger).  4 of the remaining 5 are pretty clearly about people with [High-Functioning Autism](https://www.autismspeaks.org/site-wide/high-functioning-autism) (HFA).

There are also 3 questions tagged [asperger](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asperger) that do not have [autism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism).

Should we use [autism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism) as the catch-all tag, for both HFA/Aspergers related questions, and for questions involving people who may be elsewhere on the spectrum, and that we also add [asperger](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asperger) when it applies?

Answer (score 5):

For now I recommend we get rid of all of these tags because they are shorthand for longer terms. They can be made into synonyms of what I would like to recommend be the master tag:

[autism-spectrum-disorder](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism-spectrum-disorder)

According to my research ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum)), ASD is the term currently used to encompass a variety of different disorders including Autism Disorder and Asperger Syndrome.

If we start seeing a big differentiation between questions about Autism and Asperger's, we can reconsider at that point but it's not currently clear whether someone means one or the other, particularly when the question isn't asked by someone with these disorders.

Comment: Here is the one from the workplace : https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/autism-spectrum/info They choosed the same approach.